# Change only the label text in Google gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

I'm using Google's gantt chart and I wish to change the text of the label only (Not the the tooltip). For example, one of the labels says "This is a very long label to test the width of the label on a google gantt chart" and I wish it to say on the label "This is a very ...". On the tooltip, I would like it to display the full text.

If I make the change in when adding the row

```
data.addRows([
        ['Research', 'This is a very long label to test the width of the label on a google gantt chart'
```

It changes both the label and the tooltip. I would just like it to change the label. Please see the [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccakn5870/ntectnth/) and the image below. How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#data-format) doesn't allow for a specific tooltip. and the `gantt.labelMaxWidth` option cuts off the text from the left. only possibility would be to change the text manually, using script, once the chart is `'ready'`. but tested this, the text reappears, on every other event, such as hover. and hover doesn't have a listener, according to the [events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#events) section.

Comment: Hopefully this will be resolved once it goes out of beta. Thank you for you help.